# How to rename the typescript interface keys before sending the data to server?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have implemented one interface which holds the data to be sent to the server.

```
export interface AdminRegistrationData extends User {
    password?: string;
    termsAccepted?: boolean;
}
```

I got the input data properly mapped to the related `password`, `termsAccepted` fields.. But On sending this mapped data to server as json string, I want `termsAccepted` key to get changed to `terms_accepted` for one API endpoint. And for another API endpoint, I want to send only `password` attribute. I can achive what I want by converting the above interface objects as json string and do a replace .. But I think it's an ugly way..

So I would like to hear from you..

Answer (score 2):

You can clone the object, add new properties and delete the old ones:

```
interface AdminRegistrationDataToSend extends User {
    password?: string;
    terms_accepted?: boolean;
}

function prepareToSendData(data: AdminRegistrationData): AdminRegistrationDataToSend {
    let clone = Object.assign({}, data) as AdminRegistrationDataToSend;

    clone.terms_accepted = data.termsAccepted;
    delete clone["termsAccepted"];
    return clone;
}

function prepareToSendPassword(data: AdminRegistrationData): { password: string } {
    return {
        password: data.password
    };
}
```

---

#### Edit

You can use arrow functions:

```
let prepareToSendData = (data: AdminRegistrationData): AdminRegistrationDataToSend => {
    ...
}
```

But I don't see the point in this case.

Comment: is `function` keyword necessary?

Comment: What do you mean? Those are functions

Comment: BUt inside my component there are functions without `function` keyword..

Comment: Well, check out my revised answer, but what's wrong with the `function` keyword?